# Downtime between calls to workers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am running this code in MATLAB:

```
for i=1:n
   job1=batch('script1.m');
   ...
   job8=batch('script8.m');
   wait(job1);
   ...
   wait(job8);
   load(job1,'var1');
   ...
   load(job8,'var8');
   delete(job1);
   ...
   delete(job8);
   for j=1:m
      do stuff with var1 thru var8;
   end
end
```

I am running this code on a quad core processor and judging by the output of the 'j loop' and monitoring the machine's performance it seems that there is a significant amount of downtime 'after the j loop' and before the next call of the 8 workers.

Any ideas how to reduce the gap between these calls or what might be the cause of it? I should mention that the workers need to wait for the outcome of the 'j loop' (this loop is not computationally intensive).

Comment: Is there a dependency between "do stuff with var1 thru var8;" and the next iteration?

Comment: Yes, the scripts one through eight use the output of that 'stuff' bit.

Comment: If the inner loop does not allow any parallel tasks, optimising the code is the only remaining possibility.

Comment: No it doesn't; this was originally a serial Monte Carlo simulation and 'do stuff' is in fact a statistical process on {var1..var8}. I'm just wondering why the delay between calls to workers _after_ the 'j loop'.